# Кастомная view в AppCompatDialogFragment

Tags: android, dialogfragment, android-appcompat

Добрый день
В моем приложении часто используются диалоги с кастомными разметками, и я использовал DialogFragment. Вот пример кода, как я это делал:

```
 @Nullable
 @Override
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,@Nullable ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState)
     {
     View mainView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.add_shop_dialog_layout,container,false);
     if(savedInstanceState!=null)
         {
         shopId= savedInstanceState.getLong(O.mapKeys.savedState.SAVED_STATE_SHOP_ID,0);
         action= savedInstanceState.getString(O.mapKeys.savedState.SAVED_STATE_ACTION);
         title= savedInstanceState.getString(O.mapKeys.savedState.SAVED_STATE_TITLE);
         }
     getDialog().setTitle(title);

     Button okBtn= (Button)mainView.findViewById(R.id.btnOk);
     inputShopName= (AutoCompleteTextView) mainView.findViewById(R.id.autoTitle);
     inputShopCity= (AutoCompleteTextView)mainView.findViewById(R.id.autoCity);
     inputAdr= (EditText)mainView.findViewById(R.id.adrInput);

     ArrayAdapter<String> adapterTitle= new ArrayAdapter<>(getContext(),android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,getShopStrs() );
     ArrayAdapter<String> adapterCity= new ArrayAdapter<>(getContext(),android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,getCityStrs() );
     inputShopName.setAdapter(adapterTitle);
     inputShopCity.setAdapter(adapterCity);

     if(shopId!=0)
         {
         Shop shop= App.session.getShopDao().load(shopId);
         inputShopName.setText(shop.getTitle() );
         inputShopCity.setText(shop.getCity() );
         inputAdr.setText(shop.getAdr() );
         }
     okBtn.setOnClickListener(new OkListener() );
     return mainView;
     }
```

Так диалог запускается:

```
        AddShopDialog dialog= new AddShopDialog();
        dialog.init(O.actions.ACTION_FRAGMENT_YELLOW_SHOP,"Создать магазин");
        FragmentTransaction transaction= fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        dialog.show(transaction,"");
```

layout файл выглядит так:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical">
<AutoCompleteTextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="Название"
        android:inputType="textCapSentences"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:id="@+id/autoTitle"/>
<AutoCompleteTextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="80dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="Город"
        android:inputType="textCapSentences"
        android:id="@+id/autoCity"/>
<EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="Адрес"
        android:inputType="textCapSentences"
        android:id="@+id/adrInput"/>
<Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Ok"
        android:textColor="@color/pure_black"
        android:background="@drawable/button_selector_green"
        android:id="@+id/btnOk"/>
</LinearLayout >
```

Тема:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/list_element_solid</item>

    <item name="buttonStyle">@style/BasicButtonStyle</item>
    <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/BasicButtonStyle</item>
    <item name="autoCompleteTextViewStyle">@style/BasicEditText</item>
    <item name="editTextStyle">@style/BasicEditText</item>
</style>
```

Но сегодня узнал, что то что должно выглядеть так
[image: Нормальный вид диалога],  выглядит на седьмом андроиде вот так: [image: Кривой диалог]
Сегодня я узнал, что есть такая штука как AppCompatDialogFragment, который должен больше подходить, т.к. я использую AppCompatActivity, но с ним все стало криво даже на старых устройствах, на которых раньше все было ровно. Откуда эти проблемы и как мне их решить без сторонних библиотек?

Comment: если у вас проблемы с разметкой приложите код разметки

Comment: а какая тема используется?